# How to center 2 div (overlapped) horizontally centered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center 2 divs overlapped in the center of the screen. i have one with

```
#div1 {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: -1;
}
#div2 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

My goal is to have `#div1` in back (centered) while `#div2` is in the front (centered on top). When I do:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">test</div>
```

It does not stack them. I've also tried adding a `fixed` and `relative` `position` to each element and that seems to make things worse. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal document flow is top to bottom, so when you declare `#div2` after `#div1`, it appears after `#div1`. If you want it to appear "on top" of `#div1`, you need to declare `#div2` inside `#div1`.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#div1 {
    width: 500px; /* I changed the dimensions to help small screens */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div2 {
    width: 300px; /* I changed the dimensions to help small screens */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

You don't need `z-index`, and please always remember to use semantic tag names rather than `div1`, `div2`. Good luck!

Comment: works beautifully - thank you. Also, I am using semantic tags, I just typed this up in simplier terms.

Answer (score 0):

Do these  have parent

Try this:

```
#parentdiv {
position: relative;}

#div1{
position:absolute;
width: 100%;}

div2{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
width: 100%;}
```

Hope this help! ^^

Comment: what about centering the 2nd one (smaller) over top of the larger div?

Comment: parent div will need have attr:

text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;

and child div need:
display: inline-block;